# Django form.is_valid() cleans needed values

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I am practicing Django, and I have been stuck on this for a while now. I am trying to write a basic survey app. My issue is that when I submit my form, I can see that `request.POST` contains the data I need, `form.data` also contains it, but after I run `form.is_valid()`, I am left with only the keys in the dict, no values.

```
class SurveyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        questions = kwargs.pop('questions')
        super(SurveyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for q in questions:
            choices = []
            for answer in q.choice_set.all():
                choices.append((answer.pk, answer.choice_text))

            self.fields[q.id] = forms.ChoiceField(label=q.question_text, required=False,
                                  choices=choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    def answers(self):
        for q, a in self.cleaned_data.items():
            yield a
```

If I remove `required=False`, I keep getting `This field is required` although, I believe it's due to the validation, because it looks like the page refreshes when I hit submit, while if I actually leave the choices blank, it doesn't refresh and instead a small popup appears above the label.

Here is the view that uses it.

```
def step(request, survey_id, attempt_id, surveypage_nr):
    survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, pk=survey_id)
    attempt = get_object_or_404(Attempt, pk=attempt_id)
    pages = survey.surveypage_set.all().order_by('page_nr')
    page = pages.filter(page_nr=surveypage_nr).first();
    questions = page.question_set.all()

    form = SurveyForm(request.POST or None, questions=questions)

    if form.is_valid():
        for a in form.answers():
            answer = get_object_or_404(Choice, pk=a)
            attempt.score = attempt.score + answer.score
        attempt.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('results', args=(survey.id, attempt.id,)))

    else:
        context = {'page': page, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'survey/surveypage.html', context)
```

I tried checking the contents of the form after the `is_valid()` call:

```
request.POST = {'3': '2', '4': '3', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'f..m1'}
form.data = {'3': '2', '4': '3', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'f..m1'}
form.cleaned_data = {3: '', 4: ''}.    # Why are you cleaning my values, Django?


form.fields = OrderedDict([(3, <django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x106c2d5f8>),
         (4, <django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x1055ebba8>)])
```

As you can see, `request.POST` and `form.data` contain exactly what I need, but after validation, `form.cleaned_data` doesn't have values for the keys. Why is this happening? Help pls.

Comment: I don't understand at all what you are doing with that `answers` method. The data is found in `self.cleaned_data` directly, you don't ever want to reference `self.fields` there.

Comment: But if you look at the bottom of my post, you can see that `form.cleaned_data` doesn't contain the data I need. I only accessed `form.fields` and `form.data` because I was curious what's there, and where do the answers get lost, as I could see them in the `request.POST`.

Comment: Also, for easier understanding, I have changed the last line in the `answers` method. I just want to use it to fetch the answers to the questions. I could just parse `request.POST` for these values, but I want to learn how to do everything correctly, that's why I want to validate the form and use `cleaned_data`.

Comment: Sorry, can't replicate that output. Exactly where are you printing `cleaned_data`? Are you sure you don't have any clean methods on that form?

Comment: Right after the `if form.is_valid()` statement inside the view. I have several prints there, including `form.cleaned_data`, `form.data` and `request.POST`. I've removed them for clarity purposes in the posted code, but you can see their contents in the last block of the original post. 

Do you think I could post anything else to help you help me? The html template? The models?

And no, what you see is basically my entire `forms.py`, except the imports. I haven't overridden any clean method or anything.

Comment: Well the thing is that the code you have posted does not produce that output, so it's really impossible to debug.

Comment: I highly appreciate you trying to help Daniel. I don't know why it doesn't produce the same output for you, I have the code on https://github.com/tudorvio/django-practice if you would be so kind to take a look there. I just pushed all the current changes, and tested it again, same output for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer pointed out, the key needs to be a string. Data in a POST is always a string, but your keys are currently int. So when Django goes to validate the data for field `'3'` it finds nothing, so shows it as empty; meanwhile it doesn't have a field called `3` so throws away that key/value.

You should set your field IDs to strings:

```
self.fields[str(q.id)] = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

the key in `form.cleaned_data` is string , but `form.data`is int.

Comment: And that is supposed to help, how exactly? I don't even care about the keys to be honest, I care about the values, which as you can see, get changed to `''` in `form.cleaned_data`.

Comment: Well, indeed this was the case, but I'll have to award Daniel the correct answer as he actually explained what's happening. It is the complete answer that people should see. Thanks for your help though.